# formatting and getting the total time in php

Tags: php

i got this code working on a string like '4-5' and '1-7'

```
$times = explode("-", $time);
$thpw += ($times[1]- $times[0]);
```

the problem is when there are multiple time formats like this..

```
1-2, 5-6
or
8-12, 1-2, 4-5, 6-7
```

how should I capture the time using that?

Comment: Whats your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode for that too,

```
$times = explode(",","8-12, 1-2, 4-5, 6-7");
$thpw = 0;
foreach($times as $time){
   $time_arr = explode("-", $time);
   $thpw += ($time_arr[1]- $time_arr[0]);
}
echo $thpw; // 7
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jsq9hM)**.